# I am getting a supabaseURL is required and I do not know why in astro

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I feel like I'm missing something. Doing something wrong. Maybe missing an await somewhere or an async?  (I did try looking in the post of someone having the same problem with svelte but I couldnt find a workable answer. i did move the .env to the top level of the directory struct, still didnt work.

`@supabase/supabase-js`  is installed

errors I get when I run npm run dev

[ERROR] supabaseUrl is required.

my .env file ( i did install dotenv)

```
SUPABASE_URL=<I know this is where i put my https url>
SUPABASE_ANON_KEY= <I Know the anon key goes here.>
```

my supabaseClient.jsx (or should this be js and not jsx?)

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
const supabaseUrl = process.env.SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseKey = process.env.SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey)
export default supabase
```

in my index.astro

```
import supabase from '../config/supabaseClient';
```

Comment: btw. you don't need to install `dotenv` or anything, see https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/environment-variables/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you would have to prefix your env with `PUBLIC_` for it to be exposed to the client-side.

[Astro Docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/environment-variables/)

Your imports seem to be alright and you don't need `.js` instead of `.jsx`.

You could try to paste the variables for supabaseUrl & supabaseKey as string directly in the `.jsx` component to test any other problems that you could have. But first I recommend you to check out the `PUBLIC_` flag and the settings for env's in the docs I highlighted.